# Is it possible to fully protect a home Wi-Fi network from remote attacks?

Tags: network, wifi, wpa2

I've read that some ways to secure a home Wi-Fi network include encrypting the network using WPA2 Personal, and changing the default administrative username, password, and network name. But I'm not sure that those changes are enough to guarantee that the network is fully protected from remote attacks, specifically an attack that could change the Wi-Fi network's name or password.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect the **network** itself, then using WPA2 with a strong passphrase is sufficient. This will not protect against **remote** attacks though, but only against a **local** attacker which is in range of the WiFi. And it only protects against access to the network, providing that the local attacker cannot somehow get access to the passphrase.

But this **does not in any way protect the systems on the network against some external attacker on the internet**. The most common attacks here phishing or malware mails, luring the victim into downloading and executing malware from the internet (like claiming it to be necessary software updates) or exposing internal services like remote desktop in an insecure way to the internet. Securing WiFi will not help in any way since these are not attacks relying on an insecure WiFi.